# Apache2 not launching properly on Yosemite, competing with existing process

Tags: osx-yosemite

I have an apache running in `/usr/local/apache2/` on my devbox which is how I like it. I registered its startup with

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.apache2.httpd.plist
```

when I restarted my mac, i found it wasn't starting because a httpd process already existed. Using which/locate I found that this was

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

and so I issued this command:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

However, after the next restart, the process is there and running again. This time around, I *moved* that plist to my home folder, because I do not want it to run.

Am I using launchctl wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

The `-w` option makes it permanent.

Comment: ohh, that makes sense. Cheers!